# are all laptop harddisks the same?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, laptop-repair

I need to replace the hard disk on a laptop
Is it necessary to get exactly the same hard disk that the laptop had before, or can I buy just any laptop hard disk and it will work?
The laptop is compaq 620

Comment: Have you tried Googling? The second result leads to HP support which suggests hard drives which will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use pretty much any 2.5 inch drive- if your llaptop has a 2.5 inch drive installed, and as long as they have the same interface. Most do.

Comment: Also to add to davidgo's answer, make sure you get the same physical HDD size as what you currently have. There have been in the past where one of my client bought the highest-capacity 2.5" HDD available, and we can't fit them into his laptop due to different in height.